# Is there a way to sum different declared string variables by using their suffix number as iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't want to sum manually each declared string variable.

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"
totalword=word1+" "+word2+" "+word3+" "+word4+" "+word5+" "+word6+" "+word7
print(totalword)
```

Comment: If you have created dictionary instead of defining variable then you could have easily done that

Comment: Or using a list instead of different variables.

Comment: "I dont want to sum manually each declared string variable"—Then don't put them in separate variables. That's why lists exist.

Comment: If all you want is a sum, skip iterating and try print(len(totalword)) or split on the spaces and sum the components

Comment: I know all the other ways to resolve this issue. 
I was wondering if there was a solution to this specific problem. 
I came across this exercise on Coursera. It was a very basic exercise where you had to add all variables to create a sentence.

Comment: Remember to close this question when you find a solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"

res = ' '.join([globals()[x] for x in globals() if 'word' in x])
print(res)

# How do you like Python so far?
```

Though, it's a bad practice.

Additionally, you can use regex to state what kind of global variables you are interested in, for example having a number between `n-m` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You may can try something like that with the variable in a table

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"
words = [word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6,word7]
totalword = ""
for _ in range(len(words)):
    totalword += words[_]+" "
print(totalword)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's way but not so pythonic:

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"

for i in range(7):
    totalword += globals().get('word' + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but it should work.

```
word1 = "How"
word2 = "do"
word3 = "you"
word4 = "like"
word5 = "Python"
word6 = "so"
word7 = "far?"

mask = "word"

final = " ".join([eval(mask+str(x)) for x in range(1,8)])
print(final)
```